# Php namespace - repeating Use in each class

Tags: php, class, namespaces, autoload

I have a lot of classes in multiples subfolders that I load using this autoloader :

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    $class = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, strtolower($class));
    if(file_exists(FILES_PATH.'classes/'.$class.'.class.php')){
        require_once(FILES_PATH.'classes/'.$class.'.class.php');
    }
});
```

So if i do new Folder\subFolder\Myclass, it works.

The classes in folders are all in a namespace.

All these classes must use the database class, and the problem is here :
When the class is in a namespace and search the database class, it can't find it.

(DB class is in global namespace)

So I try to put "use BDD" (Bdd is the db class) and it still doesn't work, because Bdd is using PDO and so i must do "use bdd, pdo;" in EVERY classes of the project...

I find this stupid. Is this normal ?
Is there a better way to autoload, without using namespaces ?

Comment: Consider adopting the PSR coding standards and their autoloader: http://phpmaster.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/

Comment: Try using global class like this `\BDD`. It should solve that problem.

Comment: Yes, each file has its own namespace declarations and therefore its own `use` imports. No, there's no way around that. No, this is not "stupid". I don't understand why you need to `use PDO` in every file that uses `BDD` though.

Comment: @deceze I also don't understand, But it's not working if I don't put it...

Comment: Are you referencing `PDO` anywhere in the file? If not, you don't need to `use` it. If you're using `BDD` and it's not in the same namespace as the file, then of course you need to either use fully qualified names (see Rocket's answer) or `use` it.

Comment: In the db class, yes. But if I do \new PDO, not working, and if I do use PDO, I get this error : "The use statement with non-compound name 'PDO' has no effect"
Thanks for your help

Comment: @Gordon
I tried the PSR autoloader : I works for all the classes that are not in a namespace. For others, I have the error 'Class not found' even if the file is found ! It's very strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty darn simple:

If you're in a namespace like so:

```
namespace Foo;
```

all names of all classes are resolved relative to that namespace. Any `Bar` will mean the class `Foo\Bar`, not the "global" `Bar`. If you want to refer in any way, shape or form to a class which is not in the same namespace, say `Bar\Baz` (class `Baz` from the namespace `Bar`), you have two choices:

1. use a fully qualified name for the class, e.g.:

   ```
   \Bar\Baz
   ```

   where the leading `\` means the class name shall be resolved from the top namespace, not the current local one, or
2. if this is getting annoying to do every time, *alias* it using:

   ```
   use Bar\Baz;
   ```

   which is shorthand for

   ```
   use Bar\Baz as Baz;
   ```

   which means any time you use "`Baz`" in this namespace you mean the class `Bar\Baz`, not `Foo\Bar\Baz`.

Yes, this applies to each file individually. If you want to refer to `PDO` in some namespace in some file, you either have to write `\PDO` to make it resolve to the "global" `PDO` class or you write `use PDO` at the top of the file to make a convenience alias. That's how namespaces work.

This applies to all use cases of any class name:

```
new \PDO
\PDO::staticMethod()
\PDO::CONSTANT
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand better. But, WTF...
Autoloading made me reduce my project for hundreds lines, but namespacing made me copy/paste a line in hundred files !
It's a bit disappointing...

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly say that BDD is in the global namespace by doing this in your code:

```
$foo = new \BDD();
```

Then you should not need to `use` it.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that but It's not working. Only use is working... This may be because i'm not doing new Bdd but Bdd::getInstance.

Comment: so \Bdd::getInstance does not work? What error are you getting?

Comment: Did you try using `use PDO` or `\PDO` in BDD class?

Comment: I retried and \Bdd::getInsance works, but now the error is on "new PDO", and it's not working even if I do \new PDO.

Comment: Not `\new PDO`, it is `new \PDO`.

Comment: @ElonThan You're right, but in fact it's even worse : I have an error for every PDO queries that contains a constant (like PDO::FETCH_ASSOC).
Is there a way to make it stay in his own namespace event if the constant is called in another namespace ??? It's very hard !

Comment: If you write `use PDO` in BDD class, then it should give you access to PDO without any other changes. Did you try this?

Comment: It's a good idea, but my Bdd class is in the global namespace, and when I use Use, I got this message : The use statement with non-compound name 'Pdo' has no effect.
Do you think I should place the class in a random namespace ?

Comment: @ElonThan I used "use \Pdo;" instead of "use Pdo;" and it seems to work ! Thanks. If you post an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

Moving answer from one of my comments ;)

Using `use \Pdo;` in BDD class fixed the world :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it was good but in fact when I call the Bdd class from a namespaced class, I still have the same error when using a PDO::FETCH function in the namespace... This is really strange. So I think i'm forced to place "use bdd, pdo;" everywhere... and I don't like that. Thanks anyway...